# How to handle XML element iter nested attributes with the same tag

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, find, elementtree

I am trying to parse NPORT-P XML SEC submission. My code (Python 3.6.8) with a sample XML record:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
content_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><edgarSubmission xmlns="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport" xmlns:com="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common" xmlns:ncom="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nportcommon" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><headerData></headerData><formData><genInfo></genInfo><fundInfo></fundInfo><invstOrSecs><invstOrSec><name>N/A</name><lei>N/A</lei><title>US 10YR NOTE (CBT)Sep20</title><cusip>N/A</cusip>        <identifiers>          <ticker value="TYU0"/>        </identifiers>        <derivativeInfo>          <futrDeriv derivCat="FUT">            <counterparties>              <counterpartyName>Chicago Board of Trade</counterpartyName>              <counterpartyLei>549300EX04Q2QBFQTQ27</counterpartyLei>            </counterparties><payOffProf>Short</payOffProf>            <descRefInstrmnt>              <otherRefInst>                <issuerName>U.S. Treasury 10 Year Notes</issuerName>                <issueTitle>U.S. Treasury 10 Year Notes</issueTitle>                <identifiers>                  <cusip value="N/A"/><other otherDesc="USER DEFINED" value="TY_Comdty"/>                </identifiers>              </otherRefInst>            </descRefInstrmnt>            <expDate>2020-09-21</expDate>            <notionalAmt>-2770555</notionalAmt>            <curCd>USD</curCd>            <unrealizedAppr>-12882.5</unrealizedAppr></futrDeriv>        </derivativeInfo>      </invstOrSec>    </invstOrSecs>    <signature>    </signature>  </formData></edgarSubmission>'
content_tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(bytes(content_xml, encoding='utf-8')))
content_root = content_tree.getroot()
for edgar_submission in content_root.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}edgarSubmission'):

    for form_data in edgar_submission.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}formData'):

        for genInfo in form_data.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}genInfo'):
            None
        for fundInfo in form_data.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}fundInfo'):
            None            
        for invstOrSecs in form_data.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}invstOrSecs'):

            for invstOrSec in invstOrSecs.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}invstOrSec'):

                myrow = []
                myrow.append(getattr(invstOrSec.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}name'), 'text', ''))
                myrow.append(getattr(invstOrSec.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}lei'), 'text', ''))
                security_title = getattr(invstOrSec.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}title'), 'text', '')
                myrow.append(security_title)
                myrow.append(getattr(invstOrSec.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}cusip'), 'text', ''))

                for identifiers in invstOrSec.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}identifiers'):

                    if identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}isin') is not None:
                        myrow.append(identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}isin').attrib['value'])
                    else:
                        myrow.append('')
                        if security_title == "US 10YR NOTE (CBT)Sep20":
                            print("No ISIN")

                    if identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}ticker') is not None:
                        myrow.append(identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}ticker').attrib['value'])
                    else:
                        myrow.append('')
                        if security_title == "US 10YR NOTE (CBT)Sep20":
                            print("No Ticker")

                    if identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}other') is not None:
                        myrow.append(identifiers.find('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}other').attrib['value'])
                    else:
                        myrow.append('')
                        if security_title == "US 10YR NOTE (CBT)Sep20":
                            print("No Other")
```

The output from this code is:

```
No ISIN
No Other
No ISIN
No Ticker
```

This working fine aside from the fact that the identifiers iter invstOrSec.iter('{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}identifiers') finds identifiers under formData>invstOrSecs>invstOrSec but also other identifiers under a nested tag under formData>invstOrSecs>invstOrSec>derivativeInfo>futrDeriv>descRefInstrmnt>otherRefInst. How can I restrict my iter or the find to the right level? I have unsuccessfully tried to get the parent but I am not finding how to do this using the {namespace}tag notation. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the wanted output?

Comment: Elements in ElementTree don't have any reference to the parent. But in the lxml library, there is a `getparent()` method. https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-are-lists

Comment: The output should be:
No ISIN
No Other

Answer (score 0):

So I switched from ElementTree to lxml using an import like this to avoid code changes:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
```

Make sure you check https://lxml.de/1.3/compatibility.html to avoid compatibility issues. In my case lxml worked without issues.

And I then I was able to use the getparent() method to be able to only read the identifiers from the right part of the XML file:

```
if identifiers.getparent().tag == '{http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport}invstOrSec':
```